# Rails query by number of digits in field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails app with a table: "clients".  the clients table has a field: phone.  phone data type is string.  I'm using postgresql.  I would like to write a query which selects all clients which have a phone value containing more than 10 digits.  phone does not have a specific format:

```
+1 781-658-2687
+1 (207) 846-3332
2067891111
(345)222-777
123.234.3443
etc.
```

I've been trying variations of the following:

```
Client.where("LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'[^\d]', '')) > 10")
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: How about `Client.where("LEN(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'[^\d]', '')) > 10")`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: PostgreSQL has no `len` function, `length` is the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it but you're missing the `'g'` option to `regexp_replace`, from the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

> The `regexp_replace` function provides substitution of new text for substrings that match POSIX regular expression patterns. [...] The *flags* parameter is an optional text string containing zero or more single-letter flags that change the function's behavior. Flag `i` specifies case-insensitive matching, while flag `g` specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one.

So `regexp_replace(string, pattern, replacement)` behaves like Ruby's `String#sub` whereas `regexp_replace(string, pattern, replacement, 'g')` behaves like Ruby's `String#gsub`.

You'll also need to get a `\d` through your double-quoted Ruby string all the way down to PostgreSQL so you'll need to say `\\d` in your Ruby. Things tend to get messy when everyone wants to use the same escape character.

This should do what you want:

```
Client.where("LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone, '[^\\d]', '', 'g')) > 10")
# --------------------------------------------^^---------^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
phone_number.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').length
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an active record query